# Static/Instance methods and extension questions

Tags: c#, oop

I'm new to C# and I began working on a project that needed a method added to a class in C#.  I found myself re examining the differences between static and instance methods and I'm unable to explain the following in a sample project.

My Core object:

```
namespace ExtendingObjects
{
    public class MyCoreObject
    {
        public String name;
        public String returnName()
        {
            return name;
        }
    }
}
```

My attempt to extend the object:

```
namespace ExtendingObjects
{
    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static void addName(this MyCoreObject mco, String str)
        {
            mco.name=str;
        }

        public static String getName(this MyCoreObject mco)
        {
            return "test";
        }
    }
}
```

Calling program:

```
namespace ExtendingObjects
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyCoreObject co = new MyCoreObject();
            co.addName("test");
            //Static method seems to work with instance?
            String n = co.returnName();
            Console.WriteLine("The name is " + n);
            Console.ReadLine();
            //Does not work
            //Static method from a type
            //String n2 = MyCoreObject.getName()
        }
    }
}
```

It was my understanding that static items stayed with the class and instance items with the instance per [MSDN Static and Instance Members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645629%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).  However, I seem to be able to access a static method through an instance above, but not able to access a static method through a type.

Why does co.returnName() work and not MyCoreObject.getName()?  I would think they would be reverse based on my reading.  How can I make the getName() method available without instantiating the object first?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The extension method is indeed static but it operates on on an instance. When you code `this MyCoreObject mco` you accept an argument that is an object instance on which to mutate the state. I would answer but I cannot think how to explain this simply.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: No, you can't in C# - thank goodness. You can in Java, and that was a bad mistake. If you see `someThread.sleep(100)` it makes it *look* like it's telling a particular thread to sleep, when it's actually always the currently-executing thread.

Comment: @JonSkeet: yes, i've coded too much in  VB.NET recently. It's also valid in java as far as i remember. In C# you can only use `ClassName.StaticMethod()` or (if it's in the class) `StaticMethod()`. In VB.NET or java you only get warnings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your two methods are *extension* methods, which are meant to look like instance methods when they're called. They *can* be called statically, but you need to supply the instance as the first argument, and specify the class which *declares* the extension method, not the type that the method "extends":

```
Extensions.getName(co);
```

When you call an extension method "as" an instance method, it's just a compiler trick. So this code:

```
co.addName("test");
```

is compiled to the exact equivalent of:

```
Extensions.addName(co, "test");
```

(As an aside, you would do well to start following normal [.NET naming conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002(v=vs.110).aspx) as soon as possible. The earlier you get in the habit, the better.)

Comment: Jon, thank you for the quick response and your method definitely works.  However, is it possible to rewrite my extension such that it would work like MyObject.getName()?  I'm trying to figure out why it doesn't behave like I see in other examples, i.e., http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311042.aspx

Comment: @Trebor: No, you can't extend the set of methods you can call as static methods on a type.

Comment: Sorry to be dense.  Why does the following work:    public static class StringExtension
    {
        public static int WordCount(this String str)
        {
            return str.Split(new char[] {' ', '.','?'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;
        }
    }

Comment: Sorry.  The exmaple uses "int i = s.WordCount();" which implies to me a Type calling a static extension.

Comment: @Trebor: No, `s` is presumably a reference to a string - so that's compiled to `StringExtension.WordCount(s)`

Comment: Scott, that's my point exactly.  Based on the MSDN example, I would think I could do co.getName().

Comment: @Trebor: And you can do that. That's not the line that's commented out in your question - you tried `MyCoreObject.getName()` which is very different.

Comment: Jon: you are right.  Sorry.  So, I guess I'm still confused.  Why can't I just call MyCoreObject.getName() like "int i = s.WordCount();"?  Is it because "s" is actually an instance of a String object?

Comment: @Trebor: Yes. (Or rather, it's a variable of that type.) Imagine `getName()` was an instance method on `MyCoreObject` - you wouldn't be able to just call `MyCoreObject.getName()` then, would you?

Comment: Jon:  I get it now.  Thank you all for your help.